# Commerce: Modify the order price

Tags: commerce

I want to modify the price of the order, but I was unable to change that if the order status is either "Shopping cart" or "Checkout".

What I did is changed the order status to "Pending", then the price can be modify. After modifying the price, I changed back the order status to "Shopping cart", then the price becomes disabled again.

When I check my cart, the price is same as with the original price, so I looked at the order again and find out that the price has been changed back into its original price.

Why is this happening? I'm not familiar yet with commerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, a shopping cart refresh causes the recalculation of your line item price(s). For documentation on this topic, see [sell price calculation](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/sell-price-calculation) on drupalcommerce.org and the [referenced Prezi presentation](https://prezi.com/e7mfg8u5qldv/sell-price-calculation/) on that page.

Maybe you can adjust the price calculation, by adding pricing rules that react on the event 'Calculating the sell price of a product' and use the action 'Set the unit price to a specific amount'.

Otherwise, you could implement one of the hooks provided by [commerce_product_pricing.api.php](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!product_pricing!commerce_product_pricing.api.php/DC).

Comment: Thank you so much Watergate! The documentations explained well :)

Comment: @Watergate : looks like you're an expert in Drupal Commerce ... +1 !